# Google sheet script - copy & plase a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a simple script for Google sheet which will automatically daily will do simple task - copy a 3 cell's values and paste into another 3 cells as a plain text.

Is anyone can help me?

Comment: Be more detailed, which three cells to copy and which three cells to paste the data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your spreadsheet page is named `PAGE 1` and you want to copy the data from `A1` to `A3` and paste it into the same `PAGE 1` in cells `B1` through `B3`, this is the script to use:

```
function MyFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('Page 1!A1:A3').copyTo(ss.getRange('Page 1!B1:B3'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: Frederico, thank you very much too. Will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want to do. I recommend you to use the [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), which help you to trigger events every "n" time (mins, hours, days). Follow these steps to configure the Time-driven triggers.

1) Go to your Apps Script project

2) Click Edit->Current project's triggers

3) Click "+ Add Trigger"

4) Select :

- Choose which function to run -> setTimeTrigger
- Select event source->Time-driven
- Select type of time based trigger->Day timer
- Select time of day->[Hour you want]

5) Click Save

6) Use this code in your Apps Script project:

```
// Name this function as "setTimeTrigger"
function setTimeTrigger(){
  // Get first sheet in the active Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  // Parameters you set
  var sourceVals = "A1:A3";
  var destination = "B1:B3";
  // Copy and paste the values where you want to
  ss.getRange(sourceVals).copyTo(ss.getRange(destination));
}
```

### Docs

You can learn more about triggers and Spreadsheet Class in the following docs:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#top_of_page)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)